# R merge mystery failure cleared up by column save and restore?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

Executing:

```
merge(a,b,all=TRUE)
```

of two `data.table` objects fails with the error message:

> Elements listed in `by` must be valid column names in x and y

First mystery:  There is no `by` in the above merge.

Second mystery:  The reason I cannot provide the code to reproduce the error is that I did bother to:

```
dump(c(a,b),'reproduceIt.R')
```

However, executing the file `reproduceIt.R`, (after deleting the spurious lines like `.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1e21e78>`), the exact same `merge` fails *only* if done in the context created by executing the entire program.  If I restart RStudio and execute *only* `reproduceIt.R` the exact same `merge` succeeds!

Third mystery:

```
a$AnyColumnName<-NULL
```

causes the `merge` to work, even if `a` is restored:

```
saveColumn<-a$AnyColumnName
a$AnyColumnName<-NULL
a$AnyColumnName<-saveColumn
merge(a,b,all=TRUE)
```

Fourth mystery: Iff the columns of `a` and `b` are identical, the `merge` duplicates some, but not all, of the columns giving their names the `.x` and `.y` suffixes -- filling in one or the other of the suffixes with `<NA>`.  So, to get the code to finally work, I had to:

```
#Start kludge workaround of merge mystery
saveColumn<-a$AnyColumnName
a$AnyColumnName<-NULL
a$AnyColumnName<-saveColumn
if(length(setdiff(names(a),names(b)))==0){
  a<-rbind(a,b)
}else{
  #End kludge workaround of merge mystery
  a<-merge(a,b,all=TRUE);
}
```

Since I can't provide the code to reproduce this, I know it is hard to respond but perhaps someone can tell me if this reflects a bug in the system rather than my code so I can report it, OR is there some conceivable way that the kludge I resorted to may indicate something other than a bug in the system?

Comment: Re first mystery, sure, there is a `by`. See `args(data.table:::merge.data.table)` -- when you don't pass a `by=`, it is taken as NULL. I guess `?merge.data.table` has details. No idea about your further mysteries. I make reproducible examples by writing code for them and have never used `dump`. You might be doing stuff that inadvertently calls `merge.data.frame` instead of `merge.data.table` at various points... anyway, hard to say without a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Good catch on the first mystery:  After debug stepping into the `data.table:::merge.data.table` code I found the proximate cause:  there is a `sorted` attribute on `a` which gets turned into the`by.x=` list for `a` and it contains _all_ of the column names for `a`!  OK, I'll see if I can find some other way to get reproducible code and replace the question with it.